# UiBarButtonItem without toolbar or navbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I like the look of the UIBarButtonItem buttons. Is there a way to put these on a screen *without* using a UINavigationBar or UIToolbar.. so the button are just placed straight onto a view? (or possibly put them onto on nav bar or toolbar whose content is invisible, except for the bar buttons)

Answer (score 2):

As they do not inherit from UIView and don't expose a view property (except for those customView based ones), you cannot simply add them onto views out of the box. Also, they might need to "talk back" to their bar container, which would fail anyway. Go with UIButton with custom image.

Comment: You can create your own custom rounded corner button with your own images as Eiko stated:

Example: [link]http://www.raywenderlich.com/2134/core-graphics-101-glossy-buttons

Answer (score 1):

You cant use Bar button directly on button if you like those button then you can pick the image for same and use that with the round rect or custom button.